# Problems in recursively generating subset

Tags: java, algorithm, subset

So, the algorithm generates subsets of set A by using a parameter i to refer to A[i], at each step, there are two calls, one including A[i] and other excluding A[i].
Search stops when i==n.

So, that makes sense but I can't understand what the last statement does here..

```
void search(int i, ArrayList<Integer> subset,ArrayList<Integer> A, int n){
        if (i==n) System.out.println(subset);
        else{
            search(i+1,subset,A,n);
            subset.add(A.get(i));
            search(i+1,subset,A,n);
            subset.remove(subset.size()-1); /*Why do we need to do this? I am not making any function call after this*/
        }
}
```

I tried excluding the last statement, but then it repeats elements in subsets. What's the use of the last statement?

Comment: Are you trying to generate subsets using backtracking?

Comment: @uneq95 yes, i know this isn't the most efficient method.

Comment: @MBo has the right answer for you

Answer (score 2):

You have the only instance of `subset` shared at all levels of recursion.

So after using item you should return to lower level with the same state of `subset`.

Imagine call tree

```
[]
     []
     [2]  *

[1]  
     [1]
     [1 2]
```

After you made subset [2]  (code point `*`), you return to the first level and must generate subset [1]. But `subset` object already contains item 2, so generation of [1] is impossible without deleting item 2 in `*`

---

If implementation creates new copy of argument, you don't need to restore state.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that, I mean initially subset =[ ], when I am calling search for first time, I am sharing [ ], then subset = [ A[0] ], and I am using this instance aka [ A[0] ], why do I need to remove A[0] and make subset = [ ] , again? I am not making any function call after that, where am I sharing that instance?

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> subset` argument is really address of object. Only one copy of object does exist (if you don't make deep copy). When you modify object at deeper recursion level,  changes will be seen at higher levels too. I added example.

Comment: @Little_idiot Are you aware about marking answers as solution?